# Inverse Fourier transform of $\sin^{2} $

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Maybe my question is stupid but why the Fourier transform of $ \DeclareMathOperator{\tri}{tri}\sin (f T \pi ) ^{2} $ isn’t $ \frac{1}{T \pi } \tri \big( \frac{t}{T \pi } \big) $  ? if I write the sin function as a cosine , I obtain the same result of my book , but why is this wrong ? Tri is triangular impulse

Comment: Inverse Fourier transform of sinc^2 is indeed a triangle. You can for example use the convolution theorem on two boxes to get triangle. But you write $\sin(fT\pi)$ instead of sinc square in question body.

Comment: I forgot $ ^{2} $ sorry.. I first made the inverse Fourier transform using triangular impulse, but writing sin function with cosine , I obtained (as my book ) an inverse Fourier transform with Dirac delta. I don’t understand why are different

Comment: In this post: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/71973/28112 , I show how to compute the Inverse Fourier Transform of $\mathrm{sinc}^2()$ without using the convolution theorem.  It is a triangular pulse.

Comment: I still don’t understand why if $ F [ sin(t)^{2} ] $ is equal to $ tri(f) $ so why the inverse Fourier transform of $ sin(t)^{2} $ isn’t a triangular impulse ? Sorry if my question is stupid

Comment: @ElenaMartini sin and sinc are not the same functions.

Comment: Sorry , I ‘m stupid